# Delete digits after two decimal point not round number using PHP

Tags: php, numbers, number-formatting

My number: `53.199999999999996`

I have tried all of these:

```
sprintf("%01.2f", $number); // 53.20
sprintf('%0.2f', $number); // 53.20
floor(($number * 100)) / 100; // 53.2
intval(($number * 100)) / 100; // 53.2
```

I want: `53.19`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use number_format(): http://php.net/number_format

```
$number = 53.1999999    
echo int() number_format((float)$number, 2, '.', '');
//53.19
```

You need floor() in this way:

```
echo floor($number*100)/100;
```

Or you cast to integer:

```
echo 0.01 * (int)($number*100);
```

This way it will not be rounding up.

Comment: prints `53.20`. I want `53.19`

Comment: try the next to lines, available in the edited answer

Comment: The last line prints `53.2`, and I already tried the one before (in my question)

Comment: @ArielAharonson not sure what's wrong on your side but both the last 2 solutions work for me (both print `53.19`). Maybe there is some setting/config on this issue

Comment: I'm sorry, it works with your number (checked it now), but with my number (`53.199999999999996`) it outputs `53.2`

Answer (score 0):

I have checked and using intval its works on php version 5.3, however you have mentioned its not worked at your end.

```
$number = 53.1999999;
echo intval(($number*100))/100;
```

Comment: Try my number - `53.199999999999996`

Answer (score -1):

you must set **precision** (floating point) before set this float number

```
ini_set('precision', 17);

$number = 53.199999999999996;
$number = ($pos = strpos($number,'.')) ? substr($number,0,$pos + 3) : number_format($number); 
echo $number ;
```

output :

> 53.19

[Link](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision)

PHP round float numbers with this setting, if you set variable without quoting that like :

```
$number = 53.199999999999996;
echo $number;
```

PHP will round this number
after var_dump , print ,echo , ... output will be :

> 53.2

our you can set number value with quoting

```
$number = '53.199999999999996';
echo $number;
```

PHP do not round this because it's string now!

Comment: Ok, but I take the number from a `double` column in `mysql` db. What number should I define?

Comment: @ArielAharonson you can set precision to max double floating point , or cast data to string when you select data from PHP to prevent automatic round